# Cannot start MYSQL in MAMP after Macbook crashes: How can I recover my databases?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, crash, mamp

My Mac crashed and ever since MYSQL won't start (but Apache will) with MAMP. The error message tells me it is just one database. I could delete that specific database, since it is not used anymore, but I can't get MYSQL to start.

Steps I have taken:

1. Tried to kill all MYSQL processes.
2. Set innodb_force_recovery in my my.cnf to 1 then to 2 and then 3.
   (/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf)
3. Created another my.cnf file in /Applications/MAMP/conf (with same variables as the other one) because read somewhere that it would work.

Here is the error log:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 32 in space 580, space name drupal8/cache_menu, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
```

How can I get rid of this database?

I also tried to start the database with

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --skip-external-locking --port=3306 --sock=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

But even though the MYSQL socket location is in phpinfo as follows, I am getting this error:

```
unknown variable 'sock=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

**Update:**

I can connect to MySQL via command line:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
```

But not through the MAMP dialog window.

PhpMyAdmin has started to throw errors as well:

```
PHP 5.5+ is required.
Currently installed version is: 5.4.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is just to forget about that database name and use a new name like drupal8

You also can try to do drop database command.

Please note, innodb may store some info in system-wide files, in that case it not help.

Before any action nice idea is to backup /var/lib/mysql/ folder.

Comment: In the case of MAMP mysql lives in /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql57. Could you please explain the steps. Where do I rename this? I don't understand what you are recommending. Thanks.

Comment: Just create new database and change your app acordinly and thats all. If it really one db only, it should work.

Comment: I managed to get MySQL started by using /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld  and leaving --sock off. However, when I am starting MySQL this way all my databases are gone. This would be devastating. The error is still referencing database drupal8, so that database must be still somewhere. But drupal8 is not showing when I mysql>  show databases. Any suggestions?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin has started to throw errors now. It didn't do it yesterday: "PHP 5.5+ is required. Currently installed version is: 5.4.45." But I have PHP 7.4.21 selected in MAMP and it has been like this forever.  I would say something is really wrong with my MAMP install. How do I fix it?

Comment: I can suggest you restore it from backup or hire high-skilled linux admin. Sorry, debug issues with your install is offtopic on SO.